# How can a website find an IP behind a proxy using DNS methods?

Tags: dns, proxy

I read a whitepaper from Iovation in which they discussed unmasking the 
IP behind a proxy.

> "The method wherein the connecting host is an anonymizing proxy or
>   intermediate device, measuring inconsistencies in Geolocation of the
>   connecting host IP Address and the IP Address of the DNS name server
>   accessed by the client.The connecting host is caused to request a
>   resource on a unique domain name meaning the domain name is different
>   for each visit which will force the client's DNS server to connect to
>   the domain owner's DNS server which the fingerprinting device has
>   access to".

Another method I read on Stack Exchange is

> "If you control the DNS server for your domain then you can see all
>   requests coming in. By creating a unique subdomain address for each
>   visitor and embedding it somewhere in the HTML, you can check the
>   client's real IP on the DNS server."

What are the countermeasures for the methods discussed above?

Comment: please cite your sources

Comment: the countermeasure: make sure all DNS requests also go through the proxy

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you use the proxy provider DNS or just set your system DNS to Open DNS or Google DNS.

Open DNS: 208.67.222.222 and 208.67.220.220

Google DNS: 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4

Answer (score 0):

One countermeasure would be to ensure all your DNS traffic also went through your proxy provider, by for example using a VPN or a correctly configured SOCKS proxy.

If you just configure a proxy within you browser there is a high probability that this will not affect the DNS resolution.

One way of doing this well is to use a Docker container which has no access to the raw network and can only access the network through a SOCKS Proxy then do all your browsing from within that container.